# Transferring data from one database to another using Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Colleagues, hello!

I am recently working with Spring and specifically microservice architecture. At the moment, I need to implement a new microservice, naturally based on Spring Boot, which refers to one of the existing microsevices (REST). The new microservice must periodically, for example, once a day, access the old one, take data from it and write it to the database of the new microservice (PostgreSQL), comparing it with the data that already exists. How to correctly and competently build this process and what tools and capabilities I can / should use. I would be grateful if you could help me describe the task step by step using certain technologies.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to ask this in your [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)?

Comment: Panda, unfortunately, at this moment my team is very busy, no matter how strange it sounds, and the task is not super difficult, but I would like to figure it out by the time they are free so as not to waste time.